# Using spring profile files within home directory on windows

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring boot application I want to seperate special configurations for local - non-git-tracked - startup. So Ive decided to add a structure like that: `C:\Users\myUser\.myapp\application-local.yaml`.

How can I start my jar file using that path?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my local with env values like below.

```
java -jar boot.jar -Dspring.config.location=file:/Users/work/ -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Also we can find detail on reference document.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config